# How do I migrate to the new V1 FCM Cloud Messaging?

Tags: node.js, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having issues trying to understand how to migrate to the new implementation of the FCM Cloud Messaging feature. I managed to do correctly the legacy system a couple months ago, but I'd like to migrate to the new system just in case (and for safety too).

Right now, I have a service worker to catch the push notifications, and a function that saves the FCM tokens in a database; then, from the backend, I just hit the FCM endpoint with the token and the API Key provided by the Firebase system. Here's the code in the web:

`

```
//webpush.ts
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getMessaging, getToken } from 'firebase/messaging'
import env from 'src/constant/env'

const firebaseCloudMessaging = {

    //initializing firebase app
    init: async function (): Promise<string | null | undefined> {
    const app = await initializeApp({
      apiKey: env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
      authDomain: env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
      projectId: env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
      appId: env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
      measurementId: env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
    })

try {
  const messaging = getMessaging(app)

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const swRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker
      .register('./firebase-messaging-sw.mjs', {
        scope: './',
        type: 'module',
      })
      .then(
        function (registration) {
          registration.pushManager
            .subscribe({
              userVisibleOnly: true,
              applicationServerKey: `${env.FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY}`,
            })
            .then(
              function (subscriptionEndpoint) {
                console.warn(
                  subscriptionEndpoint
                    ? 'Suscription to Push Manager reached.'
                    : 'Couldn`t suscribe to Push Manager'
                )
              },
              function (error) {
                console.warn(error)
              }
            )
          console.warn(
            'Service Worker registration successful with scope: ',
            registration.scope
          )
          return registration
        },
        function (error) {
          console.warn('Service Worker registration failed: ', error)
        }
      )
    if (swRegistration) {
      const fcm_token = await getToken(messaging, {
        vapidKey: env.FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY,
        serviceWorkerRegistration: swRegistration,
      })
      if (fcm_token) {
        //setting FCM token in indexed db using localstorage
        localStorage.setItem('fcm_token', fcm_token)

        //return the FCM token after saving it
        return fcm_token
      }
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
  return null
  }
},
 }

export { firebaseCloudMessaging }
```

`

`

```
//firebase-messaging-sw.mjs

import 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app-compat.js'
import 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js'


// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// Tanto la config como la inicialización del messaging son necesarias para que reciba los eventos push

// Firebase config
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
}
// Initialize Firebase

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const messaging = firebase.messaging()

//Background message handler
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
 /*  console.warn(
    '[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ',
    payload
  ) */
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: payload.data.icon,
    data: payload.data,
  }

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions)
})
```

`

To send the notifications from backend, I use the following code:

`

```
//sendNotification util
export const sendNotification = async ({
  fcm,
  notificationData,
}: ISendNotificationProps): Promise<ApproachError | void> => {
  console.log('Sending notification through FCM to', fcm);
  await axios
    .post(
      'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
      {
        to: fcm,
        data: notificationData,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `key=${process.env.FIREBASE_NOTIFICATIONS_APP_KEY}`,
        },
      }
    )
    .then(async (res) => {
      const result = res.data.results[0];
      if (
        result.error &&
        (result.error === 'NotRegistered' ||
          result.error === 'InternalServerError')
      ) {
        //Delete token
        await deleteFcmToken({ fcm_token: fcm });
        throw new ErrorResponse(
          'Token not registered or failed, proceeding to delete token.',
           410,
          'TokenNotRegisteredError'
        );
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
};
```

`

I tried to follow the Google Docs about this feature's migration, but it's hard to follow and to know what is required depending on the code I'm using. What should I do next to do the migration?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can either generate OAuth2 tokens within your app or use Firebase Cloud Functions, which are better documented.